# Finding the RHS of a complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Consder $z$, a complex number, such that $z+\frac{1}{z} = 2\sin(a)$, $a \in (0,2 \pi)$ .

Find : $$ z^{4n} + \frac{1}{z^{4n}} = ? $$

I tried expanding it in trig form, then by applying de Moivre's formulas I thought I could get something useful, but I'm rather stuck here and I don't think my approach will lead anywhere.

Ideas would be welcome !

Comment: Think z as some exponential form

Comment: Hint: If $z=r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) $ , then $z^{n}=r^{n} (\cos n\theta + i \sin n\theta)$ @jonnd , where $n$ is a power that can be negative as well as positive.

Comment: If $z+z^{-1}=2\sin(a)$ then $z=\sin(a)\pm i\cos(a)=\pm i\exp(\mp ia)$ hence $z^{4n}=\exp(\mp i4na)$, $z^{-4n}=\exp(\pm i4na)$, and, finally, $z^{4n}+z^{-4n}=\exp(i4na)+\exp(-i4na)=2\cos(4na)$.